# How do I populate the "Find Results" panel from a plugin in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am writing a plugin to perform searches for the selected text in an opengrok instance.

I have that working, in that you can select text, it will search the opengrok instance and open a panel to write out the results in a way similar to how "Find in files" presents it's results.

But it is not identical. For some reason the style is very different and things like "next_result" and "prev_result" commands don't work.

I have been reading the API Reference and looking at the various plugins found in the "Default" package, as well as reading any plugin code that I can find that seems to touch the "Find Results", but I can't for the life of me find examples of anyone putting results into the "Find Results" panel from a plugin.

How do I go about putting my own search results into the "Find Results" panel from a Sublime Text 3 plugin?

Comment: I was able to work this out to a near "exactly what I want" degree by looking at the "exec" command in the Default plugin package.

One secret was using the "Packages/Default/Find Results.hidden-tmLanguage" as the syntax for the panel.

Comment: I'm probably too late, but a plugin that might hint at the right path is [BetterFindBuffer](https://github.com/aziz/BetterFindBuffer). Hope you get it working, likely I'll be a user of your plugin!

Comment: By the way, I just saw that somebody was working at sublime+opengrok integration, but the work looks halted in 2015. Anyway if you develop such plugin, could you please announce it here?